# How can i send my data to server through URL.[iOS]

Tags: ios, json

How can i send data to server through URL using POST method.

My data is like below:

```
  json == {
Signup =     {
    email = test;
    password = 123;
    username = test;
 };
}
```

My URL is like this:

```
http://192.168.1.122/~test/sample/index.php/Api/signup
```

Please suggest me. I am stuck on this from last 2 days. Please help me.

Data format is JSON.

Comment: what the result u need, u need to send the json data to http://192.168.1.122/~test/sample/index.php/Api/signup

Comment: yeah i want to send JSON data to this url. please help me

Comment: if u don't mine can u give json == {
Signup =     {
    email = test;
    password = 123;
    username = test;
 };
}    ----> this url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something similar to send a simple post request with JSON Data

```
  -(void)sendPostData{

 NSString *urlStr = @"http://me.com";
 urlStr = [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

NSDictionary* info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:user.userName,@"username",user.password,@"password",user.email,@"email", nil];
    NSError *error;

   NSData* bodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:info
                                                       options:kNilOptions error:&error];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *responseFromRequest, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)responseFromRequest;
         NSInteger code = [httpResponse statusCode];

         }];
}
```

Comment: what is user.userName? my q is what is user?

Comment: put your username there. username you are trying to send. same with other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my GitHub repo JWURLConnection[enter link description here](https://github.com/julian-weinert/JWURLConnection), this will help you.

If you'r targeting an API I would also recommend [JWRESTClient](https://github.com/julian-weinert/JWRESTClient).